# NGINX head request to return whether the file is cached or not

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy

I have a client application that needs to use NGINX as a proxy, and I need NGINX to respond to `HEAD` requests in the following way:

1. If the file is cached, return code 200.
2. If the file is not cached, return a different response code (not 200, e.g. 204 or
   410) and cache the file, so that it's available from the cache upon
   a subsequent request.

Is this possible by configuring NGINX and how?

It is also acceptable for me that NGINX return 200 even if the file is not cached, but set a special response header to notify the client app that the file is not cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use add_header directive:

```
http {
    ....
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    ....
 }
```

to get appropriate MISS or HIT status in the X-Cache header.